# Collision detection, new Function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use the library "Sinova / Collisions" on GitHub, with Node.js.
https://github.com/Sinova/Collisions
I need a function, to delete all data at once. There is a function to delete Objects one by one. But, that doesn't always work correctly.

All Collision saved in colArr "Array"

```
for(let i = 0; i < colArr.length; i++){
     system.remove(colArr[i]);
}
```

Is there a Way to delete everything in the Library, directly? A new Function?

```
system.removeAll(); //???
```

I wrote to the Github-Issues a few days ago. But without Success

Comment: Why not doing something like `system = new Collisions()`?

Comment: _"But, that doesn't always work correctly"_ What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var system = new Collisions();
```

Should fix the Problem

Comment: Not with the `const`, not in the same scope. Surely?

Comment: Yes, that's true. We can use "var".

Answer (score 1):

From reading the code, no such function exists, no.

If you want to start from scratch just create a new `Collisions` object and work with that.

Of course, unless you scope it carefully, or replace it, the old one will still exist and take up memory.

Making a feature request to the library author is a good idea, but we can't really help you to get any traction on that. You have to be patient and wait for a response from them.

Comment: Thank you
Okay, then I'm waiting of a response from them.
(new Collisions) I never thought of that :D